# Matlab search for insertion points in sorted vector

Tags: matlab, octave, binary-search

How can I search for insertion points in a sorted vector?

In other words, what's the Matlab equivalent of the Octave "lookup" function: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Finding-Elements-and-Checking-Conditions.html#doc%2dlookup

FURTHER DESCRIPTION:

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
res = bsxfun(@gt, A * B, c);
```

Where A and B are large sparse matrices and c is a non-negative column vector.

Unfortunately, before comparing with c, the matrix A * B has too many nonzero elements to fit in memory so I can't just do this multiplication directly.

Instead I put an upper bound on the number of nonzero elements in each row by taking

```
counts = spones(A) * sum(spones(B),2);
```

Then, I want to split the counts array into n parts whose sums are roughly equal.  In Octave I would say:

```
cs = cumsum(counts)';
sectionSize = ceil(cs(end) / n);
places = lookup(cs, (0:n) * sectionSize);
bounds = [places(1:n) + 1; places(2:(n+1))];
```

And now I can build res piece by piece without exhausting all the memory on the machine:

```
res = sparse(size(A,1),size(B,2));
for b = bounds
    res(b(1):b(2),:) = bsxfun(@gt,A(b(1):b(2),:) * B,c(b(1):b(2)));
end
```

I welcome any better ideas for how to do this.  Especially since Matlab warns that the res array shouldn't be built by indexing in this way.

Comment: Can you give an example of the Octave `lookup` function?

Answer (score 0):

Octave:

```
octave:6> lookup([1:10], [3 7])
ans =

   3   7
```

Matlab:

```
>> find(ismember([1:10], [3 7]))

ans =

     3     7
```

Comment: This only works if the element is in the table.  I want to find the insertion points (ie where would the element go in the table?)

Comment: @dspyz I see. Can you provide example what you do? I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just what you are looking for

```
 x = primes(10)
 y = 4;
 pos = find(x>y,1)-1
```

If you consider the vector `x`, and value `y`, you would want to insert `y` after point `pos`

Answer (score 0):

For the basic
      `lookup(table,y)`
functionality
      `floor(interp1(table,val,y))`
or even better
      `floor(interp1q(table,val,y))`
could be used, where
      `val = (1:length(table))'`.

(See help on `interp1` resp. `interp1q` for requirements on `table` parameter.)
Further `lookup` functionality can be obtained similarly.

Answer (score 0):

The second output of `histc` should be what you're looking for.
It's a full builtin, so its also pretty fast.

In analogy with octaves `lookup`, you can use it as:

```
[~, idx] = histc(y, table)
```

Where `table` is the sorted vector into which the values in `y` are inserted.